# Dynamic Type in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, swift2, dynamictype

I've migrated my swift version from 2.3 to 3 and it converted some code automatically, below is the case on which i'm getting crash i've tried some options but in vain,

swift 2.3:*Works fine*

```
public func huntSuperviewWithClassName(className: String) -> UIView?
{
    var foundView: UIView? = nil

    var currentVeiw:UIView? = self

    while currentVeiw?.superview != nil{
        if let classString = String.fromCString(class_getName(currentVeiw?.dynamicType)){

            if let classNameWithoutPackage = classString.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last{
                print(classNameWithoutPackage)
                if classNameWithoutPackage == className{
                    foundView = currentVeiw
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        currentVeiw = currentVeiw?.superview
    }

    return foundView
}
```

}

swift 3:Not fine

```
  if let classString = String(validatingUTF8: class_getName(type(of:currentVeiw) as! AnyClass)) {
```

Tried this line too:

```
  if let classString = String(describing: class_getName(type(of: currentVeiw) as! AnyClass)){
```

but it doesn't work..

please guide me how to correct this line according to swift 3:

```
 if let classString = String.fromCString(class_getName(currentVeiw?.dynamicType)){
```

Comment: have you tried  if let classString = String(validatingUTF8: class_getName(type(of:currentVeiw) as? AnyClass))

Comment: Arvind below not fine i've written the same line

Comment: what is value of let classString = String.fromCString(class_getName(currentVeiw?.dynamicType)) in Swift 2.3?

Comment: it returns the class type for e.g uiview, uibutton, etc

Comment: @RibelynPunk no its different here you are force unwrapping it instead of as! try using as?

Comment: i've tried it already.. 
as it gives an option to it that it may return nil, but i need the class type which in case showing not correct

Comment: Try this let classString = String(describing: currentVeiw.self) as @YagneshDobariya answer tells you to do, only that it doesnt result an optional just use it without if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you can't use an `if let` because it's totally unnecessary. You don't have any optionals to unwrap.`if let` is used exclusively to unwrap optionals.

```
public func huntSuperviewWithClassName(className: String) -> UIView?
{
    var foundView: UIView? = nil

    var currentVeiw:UIView? = self

    while currentVeiw?.superview != nil{

            let classString = NSStringFromClass((currentVeiw?.classForCoder)!)

            if let classNameWithoutPackage = classString.components(separatedBy:".").last{
                print(classNameWithoutPackage)
                if classNameWithoutPackage == className{
                    foundView = currentVeiw
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        currentVeiw = currentVeiw?.superview
    }

    return foundView
}
```

works Fine!

Comment: i've made some edits in your answer it gives me an idea, now this edited answer is working fine... thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if let classString = String(describing: currentVeiw.self) 
{
}
```

Comment: This function doesnt return optional, so you cant use it in optional binding otherwise it gives the right result

Comment: @user1000 if doesn't work with string binding...
with only let it returns this,
Optional(<UIButton: 0x1108e74a0; frame = (0 0; 86 25); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: where i need only UIBUTTON in case

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
public func huntSuperviewWithClassName(className: String) -> UIView?
{
    var foundView: UIView? = nil
    var currentVeiw:UIView? = self
    while currentVeiw?.superview != nil{
        let classString = String(describing: type(of: currentVeiw?.classForCoder))
        if let classNameWithoutPackage = classString.components(separatedBy:".").first {
            print(classNameWithoutPackage)
            if classNameWithoutPackage == className {
                foundView = currentVeiw
                break
            }
        }
        currentVeiw = currentVeiw?.superview
    }
    return foundView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
let classString = String(describing: type(of: currentVeiw!))
```